# String simplification for regex (BASH)

Tags: regex, bash, shell

I'm looking for a way to simplify multiple strings for the purpose of regular expression searching, Here's an example:

I have a list of several thousand strings, similar to the ones below (text.#######):

```
area.202264
area.202265
area.202266
area.202267
area.202268
area.202269
area.202270
area.204517
area.204518
area.204519
area.207171
area.207338
area.208842
```

I've been trying to figure out an automated way to simplify it into something like this:

```
area.20226(4|5|6|7|8|9)|area.202270|area.20451(7|8|9)|area.207171|area.207338|area.208842
```

The purpose of this would be to reduce string length when searching these areas, I have absolutely no way how to approach something like this in a simple, re-usable way.

Thanks in advance! Any solutions or tips on where to start would be appreciated :)

Comment: Do you see any pattern here ? Or do you have some rule to match ?

Comment: Basically just matching sequences and simplyfying them, I.E: 11,12,13,14,15,20 could be simplified to 1(2|3|4|5),20

Comment: So is there a range of numbers you are trying to match against ? If you could elaborate on this question more maybe I can come up with a shorter regex.

Comment: I'm trying to match (exact) strings against a database, and trying to reduce the character count of what I'm searching

Comment: So far we know you're trying to match using a database plugin. What's the regex syntax for the plugin? Are "OR"s like this: a|b or like this: a\|b or something else? I assume character classes are [a-cfz] and parens are groups? Or do parens get escaped like "\\(...\\)" ?

Comment: OR's and parenthesis do not need to be escaped syntax is just a match, with OR's as far as I could dig up, the syntax is as above '(area.20226(4|5|6|7|8|9)|area.202270|area.20451(7|8|9)|area.207171|area.207338|area.208842)'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo "area.202264 area.202265 area.202266 area.202267 area.202268 area.202269 area.202270 area.204517 area.204518 area.204519 area.207171 area.207338 area.208842" | tr ' ' '\n' > list.txt

cat list.txt | grep -v "^$" | sed -e "s/[0-9] *$//g" | sort -u | while read p; do l=`grep $p list.txt | sed -e "s/.*\([0-9]\)$/\1/g" | xargs |  tr ' ' '|'` ;echo "$p($l)" ; done | sed -e "s/(\(.\))/\1/g"| xargs| tr ' ' '|'
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

put search strings to the file named "filter" in one column

```
area.202264
area.202265
area.202266
area.202267
```

than you can search fast enought by

fgrep -f filter file-to-search-in

I see no easy way to produce regexp from samples, and I'm not sure regexp approach will faster.

Comment: I'm not necessarily looking for a faster example, I'm looking for one with the fewest possibly resulting strings, the plugin I'm using allows for regex matching, but not for file input sadly

Comment: At least, you can make area.202264|area.202265|area.202266|area.202267 regexp

Comment: I'm looking for a bash solution to use the regex plugin included in a database

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of things you should know:

1. Nearly all regex engines build a state machine from their patterns. You can probably just put the various named between vertical bars and get good performance. (It won't *look* nice, but it will work.)

   That is, something like:

   ```
   (area.202264|area.202265|area.202266|...|area.207338|area.208842)
   ```

   Even with 4k items, the right engine will just compile it down. (I don't think bash will handle it, because of the length. But perl, grep, fgrep as mentioned elsewhere can do it.)
2. You say "BASH", so it's worth pointing out there is a difference between regex and file globbing. If the things you are working with are text, then regex `(^area.\d+$)` is the way to go. If the things you are working with are filenames, then globbing `(*.c)` has different rules.
3. You can simplify greatly if you don't care at all about the numbers, only the format. For regexes:

   ```
   area\.\d+      # area, dot, one or more digits (0-9)
   area\.\d{1,6}  # area, dot no less than 1, no more than 6 digits
   area\.\d{6}    # area, dot, exactly 6 digits
   area\.20[234]\d{3}  # area, dot, 20 {2,3,4} then 3 more digits
   ```

Comment: I am inputing the areas in as above "(area.202264|area.202265|area.202266|...|area.207338|area.208842)", However, the plugin which USES regex has a character input limit. Based on the comments from this, it may just be better to split them into that form, then query multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use Perl and the [Regexp::Assemble](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Regexp-Assemble/lib/Regexp/Assemble.pm) module, it can convert multiple patterns into a single, optimized, regular expression.  For instance, using it on the list of strings in the question yields:

```
(?-xism:area\.20(?:22(?:6[456789]|70)|7(?:171|338)|451[789]|8842))
```

That only works if the database plugin can accept Perl regular expressions.